# Hit detection in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make an aim trainer in pygame. However when I click on an enemy, the program does not execute the hit (i do not think) I can hear the sound but the enemy does not disappear. When I click the target it is supposed to disappear and a new set is spawned on the screen. I am very new to coding so any help is appreciated.

````
def game(difficulty):
    config = populateConfig(difficulty)

    pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)

    mouseY = (WINDOWHEIGHT / 2)
    mouseX = (WINDOWWIDTH / 2) 




    pointerImg_rect = pointerImg.get_rect()

    tickCounter = 0
    enemies = []
    amountOfEnemies = 0
    score = 0
    FPS = 75
    hitShots = 0
    totalShots = 0
    STARTINGTIME = config.get("time")
    CIRCLERADIUS = 150
    while True:
        if(config.get("time") <= 0):
            gameOver(totalShots, hitShots, difficulty, score)
        tickCounter += 1
        if(tickCounter % FPS == 0):
            config["time"] -= 1
        windowSurface.fill(WHITE)

        if (amountOfEnemies == 0):
            config["time"] = STARTINGTIME
            while(amountOfEnemies != config.get("maxAmountOfEnemies")):
                enemies.append(pygame.Rect((random.randint(0,WINDOWWIDTH - config.get("enemySize"))),
                                           (random.randint(0,WINDOWHEIGHT - config.get("enemySize"))),
                                           config.get("enemySize"), config.get("enemySize")))
                if enemies[amountOfEnemies].topleft[0] < 135 and enemies[amountOfEnemies].topleft[1] < 65:
                    enemies.pop(amountOfEnemies)
                else:
                    amountOfEnemies += 1
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                terminate()
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                pass
            if event.type == KEYUP:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    terminate()
            if event.type == MOUSEMOTION:
                pointer_rect.center = event.pos
            if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                pygame.mixer.Channel(0).play(shootSound)
                totalShots += 1
                for enemy in enemies[:]:
                    if mouseX > enemy.topleft[0] and mouseX < enemy.bottomright[0]\  **this is the issue*
                       and mouseY > enemy.topleft[1] and mouseY < enemy.bottomright[1]:

                        pygame.mixer.Channel(1).play(hitSound)

                        enemies.remove(enemy)
                        amountOfEnemies -= 1
                        score += 1
                        hitShots += 1




        for enemy in enemies:
            windowSurface.blit(targetImage, enemy)
            windowSurface.blit(pointerImg, pointer_rect)

        drawText("Time: " + str(config.get("time")), windowSurface, 8,8)
        drawText("Score: " + str(score), windowSurface, 8,38)
        pygame.display.update()
        mainClock.tick(FPS)
Menu()```
````

Comment: which sound do you hear? the shoot or hit sound?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` event has a `pos` attribute that contains the position of the mouse cursor at the time the button was pressed.

Use this instead of `mouseX` and `mouseY` (which you never update to the current mouse position and therefore are useless).

Also, since `enemies` is a list of `Rect` instances, you can make use of some handy functions of this class, like [`collidepoint`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidepoint).

So your code could look like this:

```
...
for enemy in enemies[:]:
    if enemy.collidepoint(event.pos):
        pygame.mixer.Channel(1).play(hitSound)
...
```